# Как реагировать на мышь в 10px от блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы мышь не доходила до блока?

Нужно сделать так, чтобы мышь не дошла до блока где то 10px и блок уже рандомно передвинулся по экрану.

Мой код:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "myDiv";
with(div.style) {
  width = '100px';
  height = '100px';
  backgroundColor = 'red';
}
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
div.addEventListener('mouseover', count);


function draw() {
  this.style.left = Math.random() * document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
  this.style.top = Math.random() * document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
  mouseMove(event)

}

var x = 0;

function count() {
  this.innerHTML = x += 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. [mcve]  ........ то есть добавьте код в сам вопрос, как минимум

Answer (score 4):

Можно поместить убегающий блок внутрь внешнего, с padding=10px – в примере он обведён пунктирной линией, но вы его сделаете невидимым. При попадании мышки на этот блок, вся конструкция переезжает )

```js
function jump() {
  $(this)
    .css('top',Math.floor(Math.random()*($(window).height()-50)))
    .css('left',Math.floor(Math.random()*($(window).width()-120)))
  ;
}

$('.outer').on('mouseover',jump);
```

```css
.outer {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px dashed #CCC;
  position:absolute;
  width:120px;
}
.inner {
  background:#CCC;
  border-radius:7px;
  padding:2px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">поймай меня, если сможешь</div>
</div>
```